# How do I redirect a failed login attempt in node-oidc-provider

Tags: node.js, express, openid, openid-connect

I'm setting up an OpenID Connect Provider using node.js, express.js, and node-oidc-provider.  I've been working my way through the examples at https://github.com/panva/node-oidc-provider-example/tree/master/03-oidc-views-accounts, but it never deals with a failed authentication.  How do I redirect the user back to the login page if they mis-type their password?

```
expressApp.get('/interaction/:grant', async (req, res) => {
// The initial route hit by the client (Relying Party) that renders the login view if needed.
...
});

expressApp.post('/interaction/:grant/login', parse, (req, res, next) => {
        User.authenticate(req.body.email, req.body.password)
            .then((users) => {
             // returns an array of user objects that match the credentials
              if(!users.length)
              {
              // What now?  I can't just redirect back to /interaction/:grant - I get session not found

              }
      // the rest works well enough (for now)....
...
            }).catch(next);
      });
```

Answer (score 0):

Just like in any express app. Think of it this way. Only resolve the interactions with success, or error if you wish to exit the interactions and return control back to the client.

I tend to develop interactions separately and only plug them to oidc-provider when they’re done.

Comment: Being new to nodejs/express I would need an example of the code. Additionally, English is not my native language, and I wonder the meaning of the word "resolve" in this conjunction.